# Intermittent rsync port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am using `rsync` to update some static web content on a simple server (Digital Ocean, if it matters) after making local changes. Because of the structure, I only want to upload certain files from the (relatively large) directory. To accomplish this, I have a series of `rsync` calls that follow the same pattern, e.g.

```
target="user_name@test_site.com:www_loc/"

rsync -av *html $target

rsync -av *pdf $target

rsync -av sub_dir_a/ $target/sub_dir_a

rsync -av sub_dir_b/ $target/sub_dir_b
```

If I run any of these individually, they work fine. In fact, even in the script, most of them work fine. However, sometimes one of the syncs will hang and return the error:

```
ssh: connect to host test_site.com port 22: Connection timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

I have `echo` calls in the script to show which one it hangs on. If I kill the script (`ctrl-c`) and immediately run any of the `rsync` lines, they fail with the same error. Similarly, if I try to `ssh` to the server right after these errors, the ssh connection hangs as well. If I wait a few minutes, I can then run the `rsync` line that failed initially and it works fine.

As a workaround, I have added some `sleep` calls in the script, which dramatically reduced the frequency of this error. However, the script now takes forever and still occasionally fails.

I have read through several SO questions on this error message, but all of the solutions are for correcting either the call (e.g., an error in the address), the firewall (e.g., blocking ports), or the server (e.g., not running the correct daemon). However, none appear to address this intermittent issue.

Are there any settings that I am missing (on either end of the connection) that would address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an intermittent network error or throttling situation from the host.

You have to design around the possibility of these happening since you can't control your connectivity or how the remote host processes.

Your best bet is to implement retries.